# Building a team of Freelancers

Tags: group-freelancing

This is my first post here.

I would like to know from experts on building a team of freelancers.

I have started my freelancing jobs and I would like to have my own team.I would like to have persons who can cover every requests of my users like designers, developers and testers.

Is getting my friends to my team is the only option or are there any other alternatives

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to be subcontracting work out to other freelancers, you are going to need a high level of **trust** in their abilities to do the work to the standards you require in the time frame allotted. Any deficiencies in these area will reflect on you and your reputation, since you are the client contact.

These people don't necessarily have to be your friends, but you should know them and respect their work.